# How to make records read-only once entered in query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset, readonly-attribute

I have a form that a user will input data into, which will then send the added record to the backend of the database (I split the database so that the frontend is accessible to users while the backend is hidden). The frontend also includes a query with no filters, so that it will full portray the backend. This way, users can either input data via the form one record at a time, or add multiple records to the query (and therefore the backend) by copy/pasting from an excel sheet with a specified format (so that the data will be pasted in the same order as the fields of the query).

I want the user to not be able to edit the data/record once it is submitted, but I still want them to be able to view it in the query and/or paste multiple records in the "(New)" record row. Is there a way to make all entered records "read only" per se, but still have the ability to enter new data (i.e. make user unable to edit previous records, but be able to add new records)?

I used this forum as a reference, but the only solution I've come up with was to make the Recordset Type "Snapshot", which does all that I want, except it disables the ability to add a new record.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/lock-the-entire-record-once-certain-textboxes-have/24f53c0a-2435-48b2-bf91-6713ff8b60ee

I've searched far and wide, but unfortunately haven't come up with anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't show the query directly(IMO the user should never have direct access to tables or queries), make a form and uncheck allow edits and check allow additions.

Comment: @Warcupine thank you for the response, however the query is where the user will be able to paste multiple records at once (copied from excel). It also contains filepaths for data files that are relevant to the record's information. Therefore, the user has to be able to scroll through or filter the query to find that filepath. What you suggested works great for my form, but unfortunately I can't find anything like "allow edits" or "allow additions" for my query. Any other suggestions? Again, thank you, and this works great for my form, but I'm looking for something similar for my query.

Comment: You can make a datasheet form.

Comment: @Warcupine in case my original description is vague, I think of my query as another sort of "form" that also shows all past records. I would like for the user to be able to enter new records, but not be able to edit previous records.

Comment: @Warcupine thank you. I didn't even know that was a thing. Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Set form for DataEntry yes and existing records will not display.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paste in datasheet form with Allow Edits = No?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291099/how-to-paste-in-datasheet-form-with-allow-edits-no)