# How to paste in datasheet form with Allow Edits = No?

Tags: forms, ms-access, datasheet

I've created a datasheet form and set the "Allow Edits" property to "No". I need to be able to past a record from excel (it has the same format and fields) into the new record row. Attached is a screenshot showing how the "paste" option is grayed out when I try to paste the record using the bar to the left of the "(New)" record cell. I'm able to paste using this method when "Allow Edits" property is set to "yes", but I still need the previously entered records to be un-editable, so I can't keep this property set to "yes".

[Grayed Out "Paste" in Datasheet Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvBl9.png)

I'm wondering if there's a way to allow me to paste using this method that keeps the previous records from being edited.

I was thinking about adding a button that enables the "Allow Edits" property, then another button that disables it, but I'm not sure how to even add a button in a datasheet form.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want existing records to be edited, why would you give user option of allowing edits? If users can't edit existing records, do they even need to see them? Set form as DataEntry Yes and existing records will not display.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about any configuration that prevents existing records from being edited while still allows to enter new records.

The only workaround I can think of is having two Forms. One Form to view the records, having the "Allow Edits" property set to No, and another Form to enter new records, **showing no records**, and having the "Allow Edits" property set to Yes.